# Pass the value of a variable from one page to another [PHP]

Tags: php, mysql, database

I would like to pass the value of a variable from one page to another without using a session variable or a cookie, how could I do? Besides this we say that the page must pass the value to another is a page that does not interact with the user as he has only the task of informing him that after a few seconds will be redirected to the next page, to do this I used a Javascript function. I thought then enter the variable value within a field "hidden" But it is not possible to push a button submit do not know how to send data to another page using a form. Could you give me some advice? I am posting my code below:

```
<?php
if (!mysql_query($sql,$conn))  {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error($conn));
} else { 
   $PartitaIva = $_POST['PartitaIVA']; echo $PartitaIva;
   ?>

   <form name="passaggiopartitaiva" action="inserimentodati_refaziendale.php" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="PartitaIva" value="<?= $PartitaIva ?>">  
   </form>
   <p> Modulo inserito a sistema, verrai reindirizzato alla pagina principale </p>

   <script>
       window.setTimeout ("location.href=('inserimentodati_refaziendale.php')", 1000);
   </script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I had to post the code in the form of snippets because normally I gave porblemi with formatting the post :(

Comment: You don't have to use a snippet to post formatted code, use the `{}` code tool.

Comment: Certainly you can use hidden input fields to pass values from one html page to another, _if the second page is the result of a form on the first page which is posted to the server which serves the second page_.

Comment: `But it is not possible to push a button submit` - it is possible and quite standard way to do this, also you can pass value as GET argument

Answer (score 0):

How about setting a timer at load, once your timer runs out, it will submit your form and the user will never know. Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("form").submit();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use some like what CodeGodie posted:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    $("form").submit();
    }, 5000);
});
```

or

```
   window.setTimeout ("location.href=('inserimentodati_refaziendale.php?varName=<?= $PartitaIva ?>')", 1000);
```

And then you could just use $_GET["varName"] on the "inserimentodati_refaziendale" page.

But either way, what is the purpose of doing this? and why do you NOT want to use sessions?

Comment: I don't want to use sessions because I created a login page using them and since I want to do more than one entry each time I should destroy the session and log in again

Answer (score -1):

If you're attempting to submit the form after a certain amount of time elapses, you should give the form a `name` attribute (which you already did, `passaggiopartitaiva`) and then change:

```
location.href=('inserimentodati_refaziendale.php')
```

To:

```
document.passaggiopartitaiva.submit();
```

Then the values of your `<input>` tags will actually be submited, assuming you gave those tags `name` attributes.

And it would be better to put javascript either in a separate file or in the `<head>` than to just throw it wherever like you're doing.

If you're using JQuery (which doesn't seem to be the case) then see CodeGodie's answer for a cleaner way to do the Javascript than what you've done.